# SUM Range Below the Header, Dynamically

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, sumifs

I have the following sample data, I would like to SUM everything below the header, preferably using something dynamic (like Index and Match) in case the data order changes.

Any suggestions?

[image]
[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWodD.png)

Comment: Turn your table into an actual [Table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)   and use structured references

Comment: Is there a formula to sum what I want? I got too many tables in my report, which are imported from another 3rd party software.

Comment: you can create a dynamic named range, then do a formula which is SUM(Named_range)